# SAML logout and lost session

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, saml-2.0

I'm doing a sample webapp project, use spring and  saml on it. I did login part, so when I run this project ,its move direclty to my identity server and there I login on this server than go to the my project home page. But I couldnt do logout part. When I click my project logout button , logout page is coming but my seesion isn't lost. So if I want login again, this time project dont go the identity server login page. Because, actually according to my project, I dont logout on project. I want logout on identity server , so want to lost my session.

How can I do it?

Thank you so much for now,
Ezgi,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only SAML2 supports Single Logout, but you may want to read this pages to understand couple issues before starting to implement it:

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/SLOIssues

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll examine it.